# Is there a way to use facebook login for multiple domains that are logging in to the same web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have a CMS made in asp.net MVC that allows users to make their own webpage with own domain on the CMS.
But when using facebook login for a domain that belongs to a user that is redirected to my main domain i receive error:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

It works fine when logging in from my main domain that is registered in the facebook app.

Is it possible to use facebook login for the ip address for the main domain instead of just one single registered domain in the facebook app, if so how?

Or is there a way to use facebook login for multiple domains that is logging in to the same web site?

**Update:**

I have domainA.com witch is the one registered on facebook. Then there is domainB.com that is redirected to domainA.com. So the login is made from domainA.com, but facebook do not seam to care/know about it, and just lock at what domain name is in the address field (domainB).

Is this what you mean by redirect or is there another way?

Comment: No. Redirect the user to one domain and do the login there. Or use different apps

Comment: I have domainA.com witch is the one registered on facebook. Then there is domainB.com that is redirected to domainA.com. So the login is made from domainA.com, but facebook do not seam to care/know about it, and just look at what domain name is in the address field (domainB).

Is this what you mean by redirect or is there another way?

Comment: No a redirect is if the address field say domainA.com